# Error running model trained on cloud on local machine

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I trained a reinforcement learning model using a GPU instance from Lambda Labs cloud service.  The library I used for training is stable_baselines3.
When I try to run the model on my local machine I get the following error which I can't figure out why.

error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'RandomNumberGenerator._generator_ctor' on <module 'gym.utils.seeding'
```

I ensure that the environment in which the model was trained is the same as the one on my local machine.
Any ideas of why this is happening?  When I train the model on my local machine it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the gym versions on the cloud service compared to your local machine. I think the attribute you are looking for was added after 0.21.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).